# Error "cannot find symbol - method isCompleted()

Tags: java, arraylist, count

I keep getting this error "cannot find symbol - method isCompleted()" yet I've already declared it. what I'm I doing wrong???

```
private boolean isCompleted;

public boolean isCompleted()
{
return isCompleted = true;
}

public int getJobsWaiting()
{        
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < jobList.size())
    {
        if(!jobList.get(i).isCompleted())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        i = i+1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What does `jobList.get(i)` return? Also, shouldn't the `isCompleted` body simply be `return isCompleted;`?

Comment: I've been asked to create a code for "getJobsWaiting" which goes through the job list counting how may jobs still waiting to be finished. I see, yes return isCompleted should simply return isCompleted as I've already declared it as a boolean. However I'm still stuck on creating that specific code :/

Comment: Yes, I think he wanted to write `return isCompleted == true;` @OP: he suggested you write `return isCompleted;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Jobs {
    List<Job> jobList = null;

    public void createJobs(){
        jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();

        // create three jobs
        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++){
            jobList.add(new Job());
        }

    }

    public List<Job> getJobs(){
        return jobList;
    }

    public int getJobsWaiting()
    {        
        int count = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < jobList.size())
        {
            if(!jobList.get(i).isCompleted())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            i = i+1;
        }
        return count;
    }


    class Job {

        private boolean isCompleted;


        public boolean isCompleted()
        {
            return isCompleted;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jobs myJob = new Jobs();
        myJob.createJobs();

        System.out.println(myJob.getJobsWaiting()); // return 3

        List<Job> jobs = myJob.getJobs();

        for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++){
            System.out.println(jobs.get(index).isCompleted());
        }
    }
}
```

jobList.get(i) should return an object that contains isCompleted(). So be sure you are calling the right object okay.

Comment: okay thanks. However I'm still having the same syntax error 'cannot find symbol - method isCompleted() after making the changes

Comment: You have to get the right object to make it work. Can you provide the complete code?